# Tegra2 device, Preparing for entering recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, tegra

I have a 10" Android Tablet which is based on NVIDIA Tegra2 (Ventana) chip (boot image shows something like: GO MOVIL, Conectate Sin Limites). It comes with Android 3.2 and works fine, and I would like to upgrade it to Android 4.0 ICS using the OS image [available from NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/content/devzone/tegra-android-developer-pack.html).

I can press-and-hold Volume-down key while boot-up to enter fastboot mode, and it displays the following message on screen:

```
Preparing for entering recovery mode...
```

I've tried several key combinations but couldn't get into recovery mode. Could somebody please show me some hints?

Comment: This is a bit of an aside but is your device a Tegra2 dev kit?  Or does it simply have a Tegra2 chip?  If the latter, flashing that image is likely to be a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

I think it'is a very easy question to answer
your device don't found the recovery partition
When you flash are you leave original schema partition intact ?
NO ?
I hope you have a backup .....
AZ2012

Comment: OP never mentioned that he had flashed the device, he is just unable to enter recovery mode.